# Removing login page from localhost

Tags: joomla, authentication, wampserver

I'm using WAMPserver and Joomla as my CMS.

What I would like to know is, how to remove the login page on the localhost
because I already can access the login page from localhost/administrator

I've tried searching on google for the answer but didn't find any.

Comment: You cant. Frontend and backend logins are there for a reason. Security.

Comment: then what can I do to make the webpage available to the public?whenever I tried to access the localhost, it requires me to login first. If I were a public user, surely I would need to login.

Comment: Maybe you have set the page to **registered users** only. By default, menu items and content are set to public so you shouldn't have to login to the frontend to view content unless you have changed it yourself

Comment: If so, how do I change it back?
Sorry about these stupid questions but I really have little knowledge about these stuffs

Comment: In the backend, go to "Menus", select your menu, select your menu item, and on the right hand side there is a parameter called "Access".

Comment: All the pages says 'public' :/

Answer (score 0):

First of all Joomla backend and front end using different session,

like you can login two different users at the same time, one  front end and other back end.

So when you remove front end login option you will lost the front end users entire facility.

Hope it make sense..

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, I want it to be available to public.

Comment: if you still want to remove front login/register option simply redirect the access to com_users on the front end. you can use htacces or simply override all the layout with blank html